# New objects not saving properly when added to tableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm having some issues getting Core Data to save new rows that I add when using a UITextField. Here is my method for inserting objects into my table view. What should happen is when I click the add button, a textfield should be added, and then go right into edit mode. Then when the user clicks done on the keyboard the textfield should end editing and then the textfield should save the entry into core data.

Edit: removed call to `textFieldDidEndEditing` in the `insertNewObject:(id)sender` method. It was crashing the app

```
 - (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender {

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController     managedObjectContext]; 

TehdaItem *item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TehdaItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];


// If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
// Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.


// Putting the cell in edit mode
TehdaTableViewCell *editcell;
for (TehdaTableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
    if (cell.itemLabel.text == item.itemTitle) {

        editcell = cell;

        break;
    }
}



[editcell.itemLabel becomeFirstResponder];

// The cell needs to call the method textfield did end editing so that it can save the new object into the store

// Save the context.

NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
     // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
     // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

}
```

Here is my textFieldDidEndEditing method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
TehdaTableViewCell *cell = (TehdaTableViewCell *) textField.superview.superview;
TehdaItem *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]];

//TehdaTableViewCell *cell;
item.itemTitle = cell.itemLabel.text;
```

}

Not really sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
NSError *error;
[item.managedObjectContext save:&error];
if (error) {
// Triage the problem and respond appropriately
}
```

in the `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method.  But if I were you I'd do some validation before you save the object.

Comment: By validation do you mean using the save context method? Also thank you for the quick response! I've been racking my brain for a little while on this problem.

Comment: I'd not use nil but an NSError object TBH.  But you still want to make sure that the item object isn't nil, that the data isn't nil, etc...  Validating data before you save will save a ton of time debugging later.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works! The only thing I needed to change after I added your code was removing `[editcell textFieldDidEndEditing:editcell.itemLabel];` it ended up crashing the app when I tried to add a cell.

Comment: Accepted! I wish I could upvote it, but I don't have the rep points yet.